# Multiple replace in one statement

Tags: java, replace

```
test = test.replace("COOL", "");
        test = test.replace(" ", "");
        test = test.replace("GRUPPE=", "");
        test = test.replace("\n", "");
        test = test.replace("\r", "");
```

This is only an example. There are 20 more Strings which I want to replace.

And now I want to get this in only one statement. Is there any possibility of doing this? Or is the code the "best" for doing this?

I develop for JAVA.

Comment: Use regex and String.replaceAll()

Comment: Are you looking at this from a performance point of view?

Comment: As a very general rule of thumb, cramming everything into a single statement isn't the best way of doing something.  In some cases, it can be fine (in this example, using regex), but in a lot of cases, you're just writing confusing code.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to replace all instances of those words, you can do it like this

```
test.replaceAll("COOL|\\s+|GRUPPE", "");
```

`\\s+` is taken by regex as \s+ which includes white spaces and new line characters.

Answer (score 1):

you can use regular expressions for that.

so you will need something like:

```
rest.replaceAll("(COOL|\s|GRUPPE=|\n|\r)", "")
```

in regex you join different variants with | symbol which means OR.

Answer (score 1):

Use Apache StringUtils replaceEach method

```
StringUtils.replaceEach(text, new String[]{"COOL", "GRUPPE"}, new String[]{"", ""}) ;
```

[Apache StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#replaceEach%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
     var array = new string[] { "COOL", "gruppe", "\n" };
     string test = "COOL gruppe test";
    foreach(var result in array)
    {
          test = test.Replace(result, "");
    }
```